# CSS center text on page converted to PDF

Tags: html, css, pdf

I have html, to which I dynamically load content, and then convert to A4 pdf. Through converting I add margins: top: 3cm, right: 1cm, bottom: 2cm, left: 3cm. I have few elements in page where I using text-align:center. However after I convert it to pdf my centered content is not in center anymore. Is it possible to adjust centering for those side margins?

Comment: How you are converting it to pdf.
which library?

Comment: @AagamJain nodejs "html-pdf" and rendering with handlebars. HTML itself is almost not touched html which you get when saving word document, just added handlebars markup for rendering data to it. Result is - it centered, but not as whole page, but if you mesure from margins

Answer (score 1):

Try this css codes for centering things

```
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto
```